# How can i Integrating the AirPush Ads in my android application?

Tags: android, ads

i want to add the AirPush Ads in my android application. I have worked read the full documentation from the http://www.airpush.com/publishers/publishers/downloadsdk/ and this pdf file [download pdf for airpush sdk](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.airpush.com/r/sdk_download.php?download=2&ei=nb1ZUKSaFojprAfetoHACg&usg=AFQjCNEQcLy1DWPJcaLLNaM0efcVETjFkA&cad=rja)

Now i have two queries:

1. We have to give the app url either of the android market or some other when we create new app using the airpush sdk. So how can we give that url like 1st upload the app without that airpush integration and get the url of the app and then again upload with the airpush integration.
2. And the 2nd thing is we have to just give that app id, app key and package name in the manifest and add the jar file in lib. and rest some code which i shown below in that activity where we want to show these Ads. Am i wright ??

   public class AirTestActivity extends Activity {
       Airpush airpush;

   ```
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       // create Airpush constructor.
       airpush = new Airpush(this);
       airpush.startSmartWallAd(); //launch smart wall on App start

       // start Dialog Ad
       // airpush.startDialogAd();
       // start AppWall ad
       // airpush.startAppWall();
       // start Landing Page
       // airpush.startLandingPageAd();        


       airpush.startPushNotification(true);
       // start icon ad.
       airpush.startIconAd();      
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {          
           //use smart wall on app exit. 
       //  airpush.startSmartWallAd();
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Is it necessary to add the layout with textview and image view in the layouts like below

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="35dp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
   </ImageView>



   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"
       android:textSize="11dp" />
   ```

Anything else we have to do for that. Please guide me

Comment: Keep in mind that users hate these, and I for one will periodically leave 1 star reviews on every app I've found to use them.

Comment: @Wug what i will do one of our client from UK ask me to do this :(

Comment: The customer is always right.  Do what you're being paid to do.

Comment: you also need a BroadcastReceiver and add some permissions in your Manifest

Comment: @Ahmad thanks for response. One more thing i want to know that when i download the sdk from http://www.airpush.com/publishers/publishers/downloadsdk/ then which jar i have to add their is only one jar with my pkg name not the airpush.jar file. Also one sample project is their which contain the  AIrPush360.jar. So I am confused which jar i have to add

Comment: Go with the jar which is included in the sample project(but it doesn't matter - both are the same juts different name)

Comment: ok thanks @Ahmad and we have to include that airpush_notify.xml layout to show the airpush ads am i right ??

Comment: I think so, but I can't tell for sure, because I just worked with the previous version of Airpush(SDK version 4) and that was very different from the newer release

Comment: @Ahmad ok thanks for your response. Hope i can finish it well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding #1 : You just need to have the package name of your application to construct market url. for example `com.myapp.pack`. So your app's market url will look like:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.pack.

In case if you change your app's package name you can edit it in edit app section of Airpush anytime.

Regarding #2 : Yes, thats the correct way to initialise Airpush.

Regarding #3 : The airpush_notify.xml is required for BannerPush ads.

Lastly the jar with your package name is the correct one to implement. `Airpush360.jar` is the sample jar provided with the Airtest app. IN case of any queries or confusions,please go through the implementation document provided on download sdk page or drop an email to support@airpush.com.